# Как скрыть C# скрипт в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть некий скрипт который выполняет функцию передачи данных от игрока на сайт где производится аналитика. Я хочу выложить его как ассет в ассет стор, но хочу чтобы сам код этого скрипта никто не видел, а использовался скрипт как подключаемая библиотека и если подключение с помощью using я сделал, то скрыть и запретить доступ к самому скрипту я не могу, как это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос про то, как делать dll-ки в .NET чтоли?

Comment: Интересно, а кто мне помешает вскрыть dll?

Comment: если выкладываешь в Store за деньги, то вроде там пока не купишь - нельзя увидеть исходник.

Comment: если тебе нужно закрыть полностью доступ к исходнику, то никак